# How to concatenate strings in list between to points within the list?

Tags: python

```
mylist = ['A','12','D']
```

I also cannot apply ''.join(mylist) and type check for a list since its all in a str.

Comment: how did you get the initial list? Could you show an example where your data has more than one set off brackets?

Comment: You can also use `backticks` in commets

Comment: In Python all sequences `s` have a method `s.index(x[, i[, j]])` which allows you to find the index of every occurrence of '[' and ']'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
import re


my_string = ''.join(mylist)
# 'A[BC]D[EFG]'

# Replace '[' or ']' with ',' in my_string
pattern = '[\[\]]'
my_string = re.sub(pattern, ',', my_string)
# 'A,BC,D,EFG,'

my_list = my_string.split(',')
# ['A', 'BC', 'D', 'EFG', '']

new_list = [letter for letter in my_list if letter]
# ['A', 'BC', 'D', 'EFG']
```

Comment: Almost, with the edited example in the OP: `['A', 'BC', 'D', 'EFG', '']`

Comment: `my_string = [x for x in my_string if x]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mylist = ['A','[','B','C',']','D']
final_list = []
temp1_val = ''
flag = False
for i in mylist:
   if i == '[':
       flag = True
   elif i == ']':
       final_list.append(temp1_val)
       temp1_val = ''
       flag = False
   elif flag:
       temp1_val += i
   elif not flag:
       final_list.append(i)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'BC', 'D']
```

Output for second example:

```
['A', 'BC', 'D', 'EFG']
```

Comment: Try this again with OP's 2nd example.